# SynthesizedAnnotation is not visible from class loader when using @JsonView

Tags: java, spring

I'm trying Spring Framework's JsonView sample code.

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-ann-jsonview

It works fine when I use Spring Framework 4.2.2.RELEASE, but it doesn't work on 4.2.3.RELEASE.

```
[2015-11-26T22:10:42.010+0900] [glassfish 4.1] [WARNING] [] [javax.enterprise.we
b] [tid: _ThreadID=46 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(8)] [timeMillis: 1448543442010
] [levelValue: 900] [[
  StandardWrapperValve[test]: Servlet.service() for servlet test threw exception
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: interface org.springframework.core.annotatio
n.SynthesizedAnnotation is not visible from class loader
        at java.lang.reflect.Proxy$ProxyClassFactory.apply(Proxy.java:581)
        at java.lang.reflect.Proxy$ProxyClassFactory.apply(Proxy.java:557)
        at java.lang.reflect.WeakCache$Factory.get(WeakCache.java:230)
        at java.lang.reflect.WeakCache.get(WeakCache.java:127)
        at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.getProxyClass0(Proxy.java:419)
        at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.newProxyInstance(Proxy.java:719)
        at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationUtils.synthesizeAnnotat
ion(AnnotationUtils.java:1404)
        at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotatedElementUtils.findMergedA
nnotation(AnnotatedElementUtils.java:405)
        at org.springframework.web.method.HandlerMethod.getMethodAnnotation(HandlerMethod.java:234)
        at org.springframework.web.method.HandlerMethod$HandlerMethodParameter.getMethodAnnotation(HandlerMethod.java:290)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.JsonViewResponseBodyAdvice.supports(JsonViewResponseBodyAdvice.java:50)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyAdviceChain.processBody(RequestResponseBodyAdviceChain.java:147)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyAdviceChain.beforeBodyWrite(RequestResponseBodyAdviceChain.java:138)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:217)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:153)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:165)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:80)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:814)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:737)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:412)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:282)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
]]
```

I think this seems a dependency problem.
However..., what is wrong? Does anyone have any ideas?

Here is my pom.xml.

```
  <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>jsonview</groupId>
  <artifactId>jsonview</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>jsonview Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.spring.platform</groupId>
                <artifactId>platform-bom</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>jsonview</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this was a known issue and seems to be a dependency problem. check out https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-13696

> Are you sure you don't have mixed versions of the framework? Can you run mvn dependencies:list on your project and check that all the Spring jars are using only 4.2.3.RELEASE? If that's the case, please share a project that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for info. but its reporter is my colleague, and project is

https://github.com/syw2452/git_syw.git

Fortunately, I could solved.

We use glassfish 4.1 and glassfish has jackson-annotaions.jar on Application Server layer classloader.
So I add a `glassfish-web.xml` to WEB-INF and set `<class-loader delegate="false"/>`.
Then this app works fine.

Spring's AnnotationUtils seems changed classloader since [SPR-13634](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-13634).
So "annotation-provided" jar have to be able to find spring-core.jar.